# Combine two merModList objects (from a model run on two different mild objects created from a single dataset) into a single object for analysis

Tags: r, cloud, glm, lme4, mixed-models

I am using the glmerModList() function from merTools to fit a generalized mixed model to 15 imputed datasets.

I first turned the 15 datasets (each with about 322,000 rows) into a list (a mild object), by doing the following:

```
imputed_dflist <- complete(imputed, "all")
```

It's then possible to run glmerModList() like this:

```
fit_gmm <- glmerModList(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1 | x4), 
                        data = imputed_dflist, 
                        family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
                        control = glmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap", 
                                               optCtrl = list(algorithm = "NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA")))
```

The resulting merModList object would be a list of 15 merMod objects. merTools provides functions for reporting the results of this object.

I am running my code in the cloud, though, and my access to work in the cloud environment is limited to a certain number of hours each day.  This time limitation prevents me from being able to fit the model to all 15 datasets (i.e., the entire mild object) in a single session.  For this reason, I decided to try putting the first 8 elements of imputed_dflist into a single list object, and the other 7 elements of imputed_dflist into another list object.  Like this:

```
imputed_dflist_A <- do.call(c, list(imputed_dflist[1], 
                                    imputed_dflist[2], 
                                    imputed_dflist[3], 
                                    imputed_dflist[4], 
                                    imputed_dflist[5], 
                                    imputed_dflist[6], 
                                    imputed_dflist[7], 
                                    imputed_dflist[8]))

imputed_dflist_B <- do.call(c, list(imputed_dflist[9], 
                                    imputed_dflist[10], 
                                    imputed_dflist[11], 
                                    imputed_dflist[12], 
                                    imputed_dflist[13], 
                                    imputed_dflist[14], 
                                    imputed_dflist[15]))
```

I then ran glmerModList() on each of these two list objects.

```
fit_gmmA <- glmerModList(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1 | x4), 
                            data = imputed_dflist_A, 
                            family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
                            control = glmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap", 
                                                   optCtrl = list(algorithm = "NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA")))

fit_gmmB <- glmerModList(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1 | x4), 
                            data = imputed_dflist_B, 
                            family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
                            control = glmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap", 
                                                   optCtrl = list(algorithm = "NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA")))
```

So I have two merModList objects after running glmerModList() on each list.

I'm wondering if it's possible to join these two merModList objects into a single object so that I can run merTools commands (e.g., summary(fit_gmm)) on that single object?

---

Reproducible example:

```
install.packages('pacman')
pacman::p_load(dplyr, mice, lme4, merTools) 
    
# Use the nhanes data from mice
nhanes

# Restructure the data so it can be fitted to a generalized mixed model
nhanes <- nhanes %>% mutate(hyp = case_when(hyp == 2 ~ 0, hyp == 1 ~ 1))
nhanes$ranef1 <- sample(3, size = nrow(nhanes), replace = TRUE)
nhanes$ranef2 <- sample(9, size = nrow(nhanes), replace = TRUE)
    
# Impute missing data; create 5 datasets with imputed data
imp <- mice(nhanes, m = 5, maxit = 1, seed = 123)

# Turn the imputed datasets into a list (a mild object)
imp_dflist <- complete(imp, "all")

# Put first three imputed datasets into a list object
imp_list_A <- do.call(c, list(imp_dflist[1], imp_dflist[2], imp_dflist[3]))

# Put the last two imputed datasets into a list object
imp_list_B <- do.call(c, list(imp_dflist[4], imp_dflist[5]))

# Create formula for generalized mixed model
formula <- "hyp ~ age + bmi + chl + (1 + ranef2|ranef1)"

# Fit the model to the first three datasets
fit_A <- glmerModList(formula, data = imp_list_A, family = binomial(link='logit'))

# Fit the model to the last two datasets
fit_B <- glmerModList(formula, data = imp_list_B, family = binomial(link='logit'))

# glmerModList produces two merModList objects
class(fit_A)
class(fit_B)

# Combine the two merModList objects into a single list object
combined <- c(fit_A, fit_B)

# The summary function does not produce the means across the imputation replications
summary(combined)
```

Comment: maybe `x <- c(fit_gmmA, fit_gmmB)` ? possibly followed by `class(x) <- "merModList"` ? Could we have a [mcve] please?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have now included a reproducible example.  The command you suggested does join the merModList objects into a single list object, but summary() does not produce the means across the imputation replications.  I am wondering if there is a way to get output from summary() after combining the merModList objects.